# Why isn't SMTP working in Thunderbird?

Tags: 11.10, thunderbird, smtp

Good afternoon, all.  I am running Ubuntu 11.10, Thunderbird 8.0.  I am having trouble sending messages using SMTP, via my Live account.  I have verified that my settings are correct, to the best of my knowledge, and POP3 is working correctly.  Whenever I try and send an e-mail, I see a message stating that Thunderbird is connected to smtp.live.com but, after a couple of minutes, I receive the following error: 'Sending of message failed.  The message could not be sent because the connection to the SMTP server timed out.  Try again or contact your network administrator.'  Any ideas?

Comment: For Live, do you mean Hotmail? Because I have one  and I use TB with Ubuntu 11.10 and it worked this morning, before I came to work.

Comment: This looks like a network error to me. Have you checked that your ISP is not blocking SMPT port?.

Comment: Heiko - yes, I mean hotmail.

Comment: Javier, our ISP is AT&T; I doubt they are blocking a SMTP port.

Comment: when I come back home, I'll check if it still works and, if so, I'll send you my TB Hotmail configuration..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked my Hotmail account and it works. So it is something that have to do with the account settings. These are mine:

1. smtp.live.com
2. port 587
3. STARTTLS
4. Normal password
5. youremail@hotmail.com

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail/live/MSN uses exchange as mail server. They will have a document on how to setup the mail client to talk to exchange. They might have some custom settings or you might not have not enabled SMTP authentication. Can you give what setting you have made in TB to understand where and why it is failing.

Comment: Server name: smtp.live.com
Port: 25
Connection security: SSL/TLS
Auth method: Normal password